# In objective-C, how to traverse indexes (keys) and objects in NSMutableArray using foreach loop

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

Is it possible to traverse NSMutableArray in the same way as associative array in PHP can be traversed, with "foreach" loop? I want to get the "key" and "value" in the each loop pass. I have an NSMutableArray, and I want to use it as an associative array, to traverse it and change it in the same manner I would change an associative array in PHP. Is this possible to do, or do I have to use some more complex structure, like NSMutableDictionary - for this purpose?

Comment: Could you give a concrete example?  It sounds like you want to misuse an array, but it's not clear.

Comment: I want to use something like for (NSNumber * obj in self.items) {
}
and then fetch the key and object in each loop pass.

Comment: There is no key in an array.  There is an index.

Comment: keys and arrays? Are you coming from PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use an `NSMutableArray` then you can use the following code to traverse the array while accessing both the index and the object:

```
NSMutableArray *someArray = ...;
for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < someArray.count; index++) {
    NSNumber *object = someArray[index]; // Assuming the array stores NSNumber*s
    ...
}
```

Another option would be using the enumeration block provided by the SDK:

```
NSMutableArray *someArray = ...;
[someArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber* object, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    ...
}];
```

Please keep in mind that arrays have indices instead of custom keys. The index has to start from 0 and cannot have any gaps in between. If you want that behavior, then use an `NSMutableDictionary`.

Comment: If I want which behaviour, sorry? Anyway I think the first solution you gave is better for me, because it is less complicated. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic if you want to have custom keys in your "array", e.g. strings or numbers like IDs that aren't increasing sequentially from 0. In PHP it doesn't make a difference, but in Objective-C you can only use an `NSArray` with indices going up from 0 and without gaps.

Comment: Thanks. Please feel free to upvote my question and my comments, since I don't think this is a useless question (contrary to some others that consider it a negative question and gave me a downvote, for some reason unknown to me...).

Comment: The point is that I don't want to have those gaps in between, and I'm surprised the array structure doesn't allow this in C. Because I don't really need cannonical keys for the elements of the structure, just an index would do. Key being a string is too much for me, I don't need it. Your solution does, however solve my problem partially, that's true.